# Is it possible to publish Mac Catalyst app as seperate, macOS only version?

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, mac-app-store, mac-catalyst

When enabling macOS support in my iOS project it runs fine on my Mac. However, I am not sure how this version will be published.

**Is it possible to maintain different targets which can be submitted as different apps? One target to the iOS App Store (without macOS support) and one target to the macOS App Store (without iOS support)?**

---

**Details:**

An iPhone + iPad version of my app has been in the iOS App Store (bundle ID `my.company.MyApp`) for many years. So has a native macOS version in the Mac App Store (bundle ID `my.company.MyAppMac`).

Although the iOS and macOS versions doe share a lot of code, it has always quite a lot of work to maintain these two version. Working on a shared project where "only" the UI has to adopted to work well on macOS would be great.

**However, I would like to use the Catalyst version to replace the existing, native macOS app. Not as universal new iOS+macOS App. Is this possible?**

Comment: Yes, you can do that by setting your Catalyst app’s bundle ID manually to use your existing Mac app’s ID. Instructions here: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev07ed024a6

Comment: @Adam what if I use the same bundle ID and use Catalyst? Sorry if this is obvious from the question above. Thx!

Comment: @DanRosenstark Universal purchase multi platform apps must the same bundle ID. If you want the Mac app to be a separate purchase from your iOS app, it needs a different bundle ID whether it’s catalyst or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this with a few of my apps.

However, with the most recent one, Apple wouldn't let me give the Mac app and the iOS app the same name. I'm not sure if that was their way of trying to force me to release a universal app, or if it was a temporary App Store Connect issue. The apps I previously released with matching names are still available and I haven't released a new app since then.

Update Feb. 2024: I recently tried to add a new localization to the app store description for one of the apps with matching names and App Store Connect wouldn't let me because I already had that localization for the other app. I contacted Apple to ask if this was a bug and they said it was the expected behavior. So I suspect the inability to add iOS and macOS apps with the same name was not a temporary issue and is now an intentional limitation.